# Vba from excel to access

Tags: database, vba, excel

I am quite new to coding and I was given this project that is beyond my scope, but I do not have the option to turn it down. I am desperate and would appreciate any help I can get. I did some preliminary searching but either haven't found anything similar or I just don't comprehend the code. Thank you in advance!

So I have a set of data on a spreadsheet with 26 columns. Each one has a category but I am only interested in 5 being: the 23 column(Name, 2 column(Years), 3 column( date), column 8( value) and column 11 (value). I just need to have a button where it would write that information into the Access database, so that everyday I would be able to record that information. The code would also be able to loop and make sure that there will be no duplicates of information. Please assist with the coding!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a query with those 4 fields and export the query.  :)

As for the dupes, just turn on the Macro recorder and click the Data tab then click 'Remove Duplicates'.  That will give you the VBA code that you need.  Or, if you want to handle the dupes, you can do that in Access before you do the export.  In Access click Create > Query Wizard > Find Duplicates Query Wizard.  Find the duplicates and eliminate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with MS Access without the VBA.
In Access you'll need to [Link an Access table to your Excel datasource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pezedEvncn0). Next you'll need to create an [Append Query](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34DRYYxEbkA) to append the records in the Linked Excel table to the target Access table.  You should set the criteria of the append query to select the records of the Linked Excel table that are not in the target table.
If you can't manage to setup the criteria then append all the records and [Delete the Duplicate records](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amRbEhQWH78).